# Angular module - Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-module

I've created the below module, following this [guide](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html):

```
@NgModule({
    // ...
})
export class MatchMediaModule {

    private static forRootHasAlreadyBeenCalled: boolean = false;

    // The method is used for providing the 
    // feature module's providers only ONCE 
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        if (this.forRootHasAlreadyBeenCalled) {
            throw new Error('ModuleWithProviders - forRoot() should only be called once in the root module!');
        }

        this.forRootHasAlreadyBeenCalled = true;

        return {
            ngModule: MatchMediaModule,
            providers: [MatchMediaService],
        };
    }

}
```

After importing the `MatchMediaModule` module into the `CoreModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatchMediaModule.forRoot() // <--
    ],
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

and running `ng serve`, the following error is thrown:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'MatchMediaModule', function calls are not supported.
>   Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an
>   exported function, resolving symbol CoreModule in
>   /Users/alex/www/mdello-port/src/app/core/core.module.ts, resolving
>   symbol CoreModule in
>   /Users/alex/www/mdello-port/src/app/core/core.module.ts

**However**, after making some minor change, causing the cli to recompile the app, everything runs without an issue.

Removing the `forRoot()` method and providing the service directly also seems to work. Nevertheless, I'd like to preserve the benefits of guarding against multiple singleton instance creation during lazy loadings of the mentioned module.

Is there a way to fix this error without compromising the aforementioned benefit?

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the `forRoot()` in the following way has remedied the issue:

```
@NgModule({
    // ...
})
export class MatchMediaModule {

    // ** REMOVED **

    // The method is used for providing the 
    // feature module's providers only ONCE 
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {

        // ** REMOVED **

        return {
            ngModule: MatchMediaModule,
            providers: [MatchMediaService],
        };
    }

}
```

Seems like the problem was caused by side effects of the `forRoot()` method.

Comment: Its work why its work do you any idea? Actually, I am new ng4.